# Late 90/early 00s direct-to-TV space opera movie where old threat re-emerges and the heroes supposed to fight it are killed by time travellers

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

This is a movie I saw in the early 2000s but it was possibly from the 90s. I was under the impression that it was a tie-in movie to a TV series.

I remember the main character being  someone important in some space station where several alien species coexist in peace (I believe the actor was a late 40s white guy), and an old threat re-emerges and this character is enlisted to investigate it or fight it. During the story, this character discovers that he was supposed to lead a team of heroes that would vanquish this threat, but due to interference from someone from the future, his future allies are being killed one by one

Answer (score 2):

Very possibly Babylon 5 Thirdspace.

Made for TV movie, broadcast 1998, ancient evil returning to the galaxy, space station which functions as a sort UN in space with lots of alien races co-existing, it had 40 year old white male lead, in this case Bruce Boxleitner. You can read a full synopsis here... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_5:_Thirdspace

here is a clip from youtube that may jog your memory

the time travellers are not an exact fit, but there are other Babylon 5 TV movies and episodes that certainly did include time travel.

Comment: It certainly looks like this might be it and the characters name even sound familiar. I am now remembering other stories that might have featured the same characters with one being the main character is now older and President of the UN-like association and he receives a diplomatic visit from a prince from a powerful alien race. Then this other character who was reminiscent of Star Trek’s Q shows the president that this prince will become a genocidal dictator in the future and gives him the mission to stop him.

Comment: The president is conflicted on killing the prince who is still a kid and ultimately decides to offer the prince a longer stay on the station so he can learn compassion and other values. I also believe this movie had a parallel storyline with a priest or a doctor on the station being confronted with a patient with supernatural powers who claimed to be the devil. 

Could this all be from Babylon 5?

Comment: @Rapheal There were actually 5 seasons of Babylon 5, and I think, 5 TV movies plus a short lived spin off called Crusade. It would be easy to get details from several episodes mixed up. if you have time you can trawl through the episode recap on TV tropes and try and pin it down...

Comment: here is a link to the TV Tropes page... https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Recap/BabylonFive

Comment: Found the one with the prince and the demon:

Comment: “ The station prepares to celebrate the tenth anniversary of the founding of The Intestellar Alliance, but Babylon 5 being what it is, things are certain not to go smoothly. Colonel Lochley finds herself seeking the assistance of a priest in order to deal with a demonic possession, and President Sheridan receives an unexpected guest forecasting the destruction of the Earth Alliance in the future if Sheridan doesn't take the life of an innocent Centauri prince.”

Comment: I’m now trying to see where the “characters who are meant to stop re-emerging ancient threat are being killed by someone with knowledge from the future” comes from but I am almost sure it’s also Babylon 5.